# Why won't my regex lookback work on a URL using Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to have this regex:

```
.match(/wtflungcancer.com\/\S*(?<!js)/i)
```

NOT match the following string based on the fact that 'js' is present. However, the following matches the entire URL:

```
"http://www.wtflungcancer.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.32.0-2013.04.03".match(/wtflungcancer.com\/\S*(?<!js)/i)
```

Comment: what match you want ? not clear..

Comment: I would like a nil result for the above (if the url above contains the string "js")

Comment: there are 2 `js` i can see.. which want you want to match ?

Comment: This is a good case for not using a regex for _everything_ or to do _everything_. Why not `string.match(/pattern/) unless string.include? "js"` ?

Comment: '.js' would be best. Thank you for catching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because \S* eats all the characters, so the lookbehind is never activated.

Something like this should work:

```
/wtflungcancer.com(?!\S*\.js)/i
```

Basically

- do not let the * consume all characters
- instead of using a lookbehind, use a lookahead
- search for strings containing wtflungcancer.com NOT followed by a string containing ".js"

-- EDIT: more explanation added --

**What is the difference between**

```
"wtflungcancer.com\S*(?<!\.js)"
```

**and**

```
"wtflungcancer.com(?!\S*\.js)"
```

**They look really similar!**

Lookarounds (lookahead and lookbehind) in regular expressions tell the regexp engine when a match is correct or not: they do not consume characters of the string.

Especially lookbehinds tell the regexp engine to look backwards, in your case the lookbehind wasn't anchored on the right side, so the "\S*" just consumed all the non whitespace characters in the string.

For example, this regexp can work for finding url NOT ending with ".js":

```
wtflungcancer.com\S+(?<!\.js)$
```

See? The right side of the lookbehind is anchored using the end of string metacharacter.

In our case, though we couldn't hook anything to the right side, so I switched from **lookbehind** to **lookahead**

So, the real regular expression just matches "wtflungcancer.com": at that point, the lookahead tells the regexp engine: "In order for this match to be correct, this string must not be followed by a sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by '.js'". This works because lookaheads do not consume actual characters, they just move on character by character to see if the match is good or not.

Comment: Thanks for IDing /S as the culprit. However, I cannot allow spaces, since I am matching URLs (out of a html body). Anyway to allow \S*?

Comment: Sure, see the revised regexp!

Comment: I'm sorry, why exactly is the \S not eating the chars in the above case (been at this for hours now... sorry for asking potentially obvious Qs).

Comment: You are great! Did you take a lot of CS theory? I did not and therefore I always look for the algorithmic solution and break a problem into cases. I think this is a common problem programmers have with little hardcore CS.

Comment: I actually have taken CS courses, but most of the things I know about regular expressions are from The Book! Mastering Regular Expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this pattern:

```
wtflungcancer.com\/(?>[^\s.]++|\.++(?!js))*(?!\.)
```

Explanations:

The goal is to allow all characters that are not a space or a dot followed by `js`:

```
(?>                # open an atomic group
    [^\s.]++       # all characters but white characters and .
  |                # OR
    \.++(?!js)     # . not followed by js
)*                 # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
```

To be sure that your pattern check all the url string, i add a lookahead that check if a dot don't follow.

Comment: Why not use the expanded regex with the `x` flag? It's _always_ better IMO. (and you'll get an upvote from me;)

Comment: iain, could you please tell me why '.js' does not work with this?

Comment: @JacksonHenley: because the dot is allowed only if it is not followed by `js`